# How to recive second command while last command not completed?

Tags: c++

How to recive second command while last command not completed?
I have a application that receive command from message queue and process parser command to do something.
But if last command is "start" and it need some time to completed, like 1 minute in the while loop.
In the same time, another command "stop" incoming, how to implement? by thread?

```
main()
{

    while(true)
    {
        rc = mq_receive(rmqID, rbuff)
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            cout <<"receive timeout !!"<< endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"receive message : "<< rbuff << endl;
            std::string cmd = rbuff;
            
            if (cmd == "start")
            {           
                cout <<"[receive message] flash_cmd = true"<< endl;
                flash_cmd = true;
            }
            else if (cmd == "stop")
            {           
                cout <<"[receive message] stop command = true"<< endl;
                stop_cmd = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout <<"[receive message] Command error!"<< endl;
            }
        }

        if (stop_cmd == true)
        {
            cout <<"stop process ......."<< endl;
            stop_flag = true;
        }

        if (flash_cmd == true)
        {
            cout <<"[programming] Start install Processing"<< endl;
            while
            {
              // do flash....
              if(stop_flag == true)
              {
                  break;
              }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Execute it in a separate thread then, perhaps use `std::async`.

Comment: I would implement a message queue for each receiver if order of them is important.

Comment: std::async, OK. I will study this, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do two things at the same time, such as executing one message and simultaneously checking if you have received another, then the easiest solution would probably be starting a thread.

However, be aware that you cannot poke a thread and tell it to just stop. If you want to be able to stop your "execute command" thread early, then you have to structure it something like (pseudo code):

```
void threadFunc(std::atomic_bool stop) {
  do_first_part();
  if(stop)
    return;

  do_second_part();
  if(stop)
    return;
...
```

The point is that *you* have to explicitly look for the stop condition yourself, and have the thread self-terminate if it is required to stop. Depending on what it is doing that takes time, you may also be able to use [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to signal your thread.

Comment: Yes, I want to use stop command to stop "execute command", std::condition_variable, OK, I will study this, thx.